# node.js express and regular expressions

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, server

Hi friends I am working with node.js and express. I have some endpoints and inside there are dynamic files every file have a name of an IP for example services/192.168.0.1.html, service/192.168.0.11.html, service/192.168.0.15 etc. So I want to make a dynamic route  like this code:

```
app.get('/endpointej/**REGEXP**forIP.html', (req, res) => {
  
var ruta = {
    root: path.join(__dirname + 'endpoint/)
        }

res.sendFile("IPfiledinamic.html",ruta)

});
```

Can some one help me out please ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
// route is for GET /test/1.1.1.1.html, but not for GET /test/1.2.3.html
app.get(/test\/([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\.html/, (req, res) => {
  const ipRegex = /^\/test\/((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\.html$/
  // do more here...
  res.status(200).send(`matches, ${req.url.match(ipRegex)}`)
})
```